# Append dataframe column values to an array by comparing the column values

Tags: python, python-3.x, pandas, dataframe

I have a data-frame with mail id and result.

```
      Mail id        result
0 xyz@gmail.com     fail
1 xyz@yahoo.com     pass
2 pqr@gmail.com     not attempted
3 tuv@gmail.com     not attempted
4 123@gmail.com     fail
5 ABC@gmail.com     not attempted
```

From the above data, need to get mail into an array by the result

Ex: If result is equal to **'Fail'** then failed one's mail id should get in an array/list called failed.. , Similarly for **'not attempted'**.

```
failed = ['xyz@gmail.com', '123@gmail.com']
not attempted = ['pqr@gmail.com', 'tuv@gmail.com', 'ABC@gmail.com']
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can filter values separately:

```
failed = df.loc[df['result'].eq('fail'), 'Mail id'].tolist()

notattempted = df.loc[df['result'].eq('not attempted'), 'Mail id'].tolist()
```

Or create `Series` with aggregate `list`s and then select by index:

```
s = df.groupby('result')['Mail id'].agg(list)

failed = s.loc['failed']
notattempted = s.loc['not attempted']
```

---

```
failed = s['failed']
notattempted = s['not attempted']
```

Comment: How can I get both fail and notattempted mail in a single list? with pandas @jezrael

Comment: @manojkumar - Do you think `L = failed + notattempted` ?

Comment: Need a list from dataframe @jezrael

Comment: @manojkumar - So need `both= df.loc[df['result'].isin(['fail','not attempted']), 'Mail id'].tolist()` ?

Answer (score 0):

Please try this.

```
import pandas as pd

// let df is the basic dataframe
result_df = pd.DataFrame()

// get all different result values
result_df['idx_str'] = list(set(df['result']))

def separate_by_result(idx_str):
   str_df = df[df['result'] == idx_str]
   return list(str_df['Mail id'])

// show result as one new column
result_df['result_list'] = result_df['idx_str'].apply(separate_by_result)
```

`result_df` will be what you want.